# Function to check for first blank cell

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

so, I'm attempting to define a custom function that returns the row number of the first blank cell it finds within a custom range.

```
function checkForBlank(startRow,startCol) {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var checkRow = startRow;
  var checkCol = startCol;
 var range = sheet.getRange(checkRow, checkCol);
 var i = checkRow;
  while (i < 100) {

    if(range.isBlank()) {

    return 5;


    } 
else { checkRow++; i++; }


}

}
```

The problem I'm having, is that whenever the first cell I'm checking isn't blank, the return value is blank. I can't figure out if there's an issue with my else statement or with using a loop. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of what is the format of your `startRow` and `startCol` variables, nor to understand what you are trying to do but I think you should update the variable `range` in the while loop, because `isBlank` tests if the whole range is blank or not : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isBlank%28%29

Comment: The `startRow` and `startCol` are both integers that I'm trying to use to reference a single cell by listing row number and column number

Comment: Ok so
while (checkRow< 100) {
  var range = sheet.getRange(checkRow, checkCol);    
  if(range.isBlank()) {
    return 5;
  } 
  else { checkRow++;}
}
should work no ?